# Python Pandas str.contains() with hyperlinks in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hyperlink

I have two pandas dataframes like so:

df1

| site | link |
| --- | --- |
| retailer_site1 | https://www.retailer_site1.com |
| ... | ... |
| retailer_siteX | https://www.retailer_siteX.com |

df2

| site | link |
| --- | --- |
| retailer_site1 | https://www.retailer_site1.com |
| ... | ... |
| retailer_siteY | https://www.retailer_siteY.com |

So I want to go through df2 and find instances of links from df2 in df1. Here's my code:

```
    for row in df2['link'].astype(str):
        boolean_findings = df1['link'].str.contains(row)
```

When I print boolean_findings, I'm getting all false, which I know can't be true because I'm seeing matches locally on my excel files:

| boolean_findings |
| --- |
| False |
| False |
| ... |
| False |

What I want to know is why the hyperlink string text is not being matched with it's equivalent on the first df, and what can I do to match the sites.

Comment: Do you even have to do it that way?  Could you just merge the two dataframes where the link is in df1?

Comment: `df2["link"].isin(df1["link"])`

Comment: @brb because df.merge() is coming up with zero matches. There's a problem with the dtype or the fact that it's not matching with each other.

Comment: @Riley this is an optimization, thank you. The boolean still comes up as false, so there's got to be something wrong with the hyperlinks in the dataframe.

Comment: Given your comments this is not gonna be something we can solve as it is peculiar to the exact way your data is formatted and probably read in. I would suggest trying .str.strip() to clear out any whitespace that may be causing an issue. You could also use a regex to strip it down to only a particular set of character say [A-Za-z/\.:] and see if that solves it

Comment: @born_naked I took a look and noticed some websites have a "(" and ")" included in their links, which might be throwing off the links. I tried 'df1['link'].replace(to_replace="(", value="\\(")' but it's not seeming to work.

Comment: it seems fairly likely that just the alphabetic characters would be enough to uniquely ID the columns, so I would try creating a column in each dataset of just that  (using regex replace) then try sort is using the isin() Riley recommended. If that doesn't work, try post a bigger piece of your code or just scrap it and start anew as might be some "d'oh" level mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*I took a look and noticed some websites have a `(` and `)` included in their links, which might be throwing off the links*

It seems you need to only account for alphanumeric/underscore chars when comparing the links, you can use

```py
df2["link"].str.replace(r'\W+','', regex=True).isin(
    df1["link"].str.replace(r'\W+','', regex=True))
```

The `.str.replace(r'\W+','', regex=True)` part will remove any chars other than letters, diacritics, digits and connector punctuation (most common char is underscore among them) from the links.

Comment: I got the following error for regex in the replace: `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`. When I remove the `regex=True`, it doesn't error out but it doesn't replace it either. I think I'll look into the `re` module to sort this out, but thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: @GH Make sure you use the latest Pandas version. `pip install -U pandas`. This code has been tested against your data and proved working.